# In ASP.NET, loading content into master page dynamically

Tags: asp.net, ajax, scriptmanager

I have three pages Main.master, Default.aspx and Foo.aspx. I want to load content page Default.pasx and Foo.aspx into master page dynamically.

Is it possible using ASP.NET ScriptManager  and UpdatePanel?

Comment: Do you want to assign Master Page dynamically?

Comment: I have nav menu in master page. I don't want to postback master page. only content page will be reloaded after menu click

Comment: As per my knowledge, whenever any contain page post back then it will automatically call post back of Master Page.